# Use Esri CityEngine features external code

Tags: python, unix, gis, openstreetmap, esri

I am trying to automatize the process of importing GIS data from OpenStreetMap to CityEngine, generating the 3D model I need and exporting it. CityEngine provides a Python scripting feature inside the application, but Esri does not provide any API.

I first installed Jython on and all the needed sw on my unix machine, set the java classpath ecc... and tried to run Python scripts from outside CityEngine but I still have some problems importing some java modules.

I asked on the CityEngine forum and they say:

> "this is currently not possible. you need to run an instance of CityEngine for these tasks."
>
> ...
>
> "the closest thing possible for this is to run an instance of CE and work with listeners".

Any idea on how can I make this work? How can I use listeners to interact with the running instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not from the ESRI frontier, but from the 3D OSM side, so I try to answer:

The transformation process for 3D building outlines is a bit complex and depends sometimes on picking the right values: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_Buildings
Thus I recommend to use an existing 3D exporter for OSM, like [OSM2World](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM2World) (Java). Sadly there is currently no highlevel export like CityGML that can be used for importing to CityEngine. So you might combine both just in the 3D modeller itself http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_animation
Please keep in mind, that OSM has a copyleft license that might affect the mix.